# React app not rendering in IE 11 even with polyfills

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, polyfills, ie11-developer-tools

I have a fully built React application that I would like to deploy on IE 11, but been having no success but a white page.

For the sake of testing, I created a dummy app using npx create-react-app and attempted to launch on IE 11/Edge. Installing 'react-app-polyfill' and importing on 'react-app-polyfill/ie11' and 'react-app-polyfill/stable' on line 1 & 2 of index.js, I also included "last 1 ie version" in the browserlist.development inside the package.json file.

Every resource online points to react needing polyfill to be viewable on IE 11 but I haven't had any success. Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any error on your console ?

Comment: No errors in console

Answer (score 0):

What is your `react-scripts` version? The issue is most likely related to `react-scripts` version 3.3.0. You could find many issue reports in GitHub, for example: [IE11 support doesn't work in dev mode, even after adding all polyfills and enabling ie11 support](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197), [Why application created using create-react-app is not working in IE browser?](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195).

It can still work with `react-scripts@3.2.0`. You could try to revert back to 3.2.0 as a workaround. Please also remember to delete `.cache` folder in `node_modules` and delete IE browser cache then try again.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried reverting back to 3.2.0 when CRA defaults to 3.3.1 but still no luck. Also deleted node_modules .cache and browser cache. All it shows is "You need to enable Javascript to run this app." on IE 11 but that's just the text inside <noscript>. The spinning react icon still doesn't display.

Comment: Have you followed [the steps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135465/how-to-enable-javascript-in-windows) to enable JavaScript in IE? Check it in your IE, if it still doesn't work, please provide [a minimal sample to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).